# Using fetch with async/await returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm trying to fetch this public API using fetch with async and await, but the fetch method is returning an [object Object]:

The class I'm using to fetch the API:

```
class FetchAnimalApi {
  async getAnimalInfo(animal) {
    const request = await fetch(`http://my_api_url.com/${animal}`);
    const response = await request.json();

    return `${animal} goes like ${response.sound}`;
  }
}
```

The structure the API is returning (if the animal is a pig):

```
{"color": "pink", "sound": "roinc"}
```

I'm importing my class in another file and calling it as:

```
const animals = new FetchAnimalApi();
console.log(animals.getAnimalInfo('pig'));
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Now my console.log() shows exactly what I want to print, but when I return the response, I'm still getting [object Object]:

```
function getInfo() {
  const animals = new FetchAnimalApi();

  return animals.getAnimalInfo('pig').then(result => result);
}
```

While debugging, I realized that [object Object] is being printed in my screen right after `const request = await fetch(`http://my_api_url.com/${animal}`)` line is executed.

Comment: `[object Object]` is probably just because of a string conversion in your final output.  If you `console.log()` the output directly, you should see the desired object.  You can't put an object into a template literal and get the properties printed out.  Also, `getAnimailInfo()` returns a promise.  So, you have to either use `await` with it or `.then()` to get the value from that promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 _You can't put an object into a template literal and get the properties printed out_? why do you think so?

Comment: @alexmac: Because template literals convert their "arguments" to strings and the default string representation of an object is `[object Object]`, i.e. not a list of properties.

Comment: Because a template literal does a string conversion of the object and the default string conversion of an object gives you `[object Object]`.  See the console output for this: https://jsfiddle.net/me0g20cx/.  You could override `.toString()` on your object and provide a custom string conversion if you wanted, but template literals don't do that on their own.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, I know about that. I just don't understand how it's related to the question. In the template string above, both variables are strings, not objects.

Comment: @alexmac - That depends upon what `response.sound` is.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's a string, OP added the expected response: `{"color": "pink", "sound": "roinc"}`

Comment: `animals.getAnimalInfo('pig').then(result => result);` returns a promise.  You seem to not understand that your `getAnimalInfo()` function returns a promise and nothing you do it going to make it return the actual value.  The caller of `getAnimalInfo()` needs to either use await to get the result or use `.then()` to get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `console.log(animals.getAnimalInfo('pig'));` this way. `animals.getAnimalInfo` returns a promise. To get result, you should use `then` callback:

```
const animals = new FetchAnimalApi();
animals
  .getAnimalInfo('pig')
  .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Since OP is using `await` everywhere else, the answer should probably offer `await` as an option too, not only `.then()`.

Comment: I wanted to suggest a solution with `async/await`, but it doesn't make sense in this context. Create a new function just to print the result of `getAnimalInfo()`...

Comment: Helped me a bit! But still no success ): I edited the question no explain further.

Comment: @Anna How do you use `getInfo()`? If so: `console.log(getInfo())`, then it's still incorrect. `getInfo` returns a promise, you need use `then` callback to get the result.

Comment: The result from getInfo() is being set to a computed property (I'm using Ember). I'm already resolving the promise when calling `animals.getAnimalInfo('pig').then(result => result)`, isn't it? I just need getInfo() to hold the formatted input.

Comment: @Anna no, the promise is not resolved, when you just add an additional `then` callback. That callback is calling only then, when a previous async operation is finished.

Comment: Does anybody know a way that I can pass the property returned by the async function to a variable? I've successfully used const [animal1, animal2] = await Promise.all([asyncAnimal1return, asyncAnimal2return]); and then console.log(`${animal1}, ${animal2}`); but I can't seem to get animalList[1].species[0] = `${animal1}`; to work and I'm not sure why. They're both in the same async function etc.